# What's wrong with this bash negation of a logical expression?

Tags: bash

This bash doesn't parse

```
if ! [[ mkdir -p "$available"
     && mkdir -p "$enabled"
     && mkdir -p "$logroot"
     && chmod 755 "$available" "$enabled" "$logroot" ]]
then
    echo "Could not make $available, $enabled, and $logroot."
    exit 1;
fi
```

What's the correct form?

Comment: `[[ ]]` is syntax that acts as an extended version of the command named `test`. It's not a general-purpose grouping operator, but something used for doing things for which, well, you'd traditionally use the `test` command (and a few extra items, such as pattern-match and regex expressions, that conventional `test` couldn't handle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute multiple commands chained with `&&`, then `[[ ... ]]` is not appropriate.
It seem this is what you intended:

```
if ! { mkdir -p "$available" &&
     mkdir -p "$enabled" &&
     mkdir -p "$logroot" &&
     chmod 755 "$available" "$enabled" "$logroot"; }
then
    echo "Could not make $available, $enabled, and $logroot."
    exit 1
fi
```

To answer your follow-up question, the equivalent of `if(!(a && !b && c))` would be:

```
if ! (a && ! b && c); then
    # ...
fi
```

That is, `!` binds only to the term next to it,
and you need to put a space around `!`. (Thanks [@that-other-guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy))

Or even better, you can avoid a `(...)` subshell by using grouping within `{ ...; }` instead (thanks [@charles-duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)):

```
if ! { a && ! b && c; }; then
    # ...
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted (C-style) `if(!(a && !b && c))` where the not operator binds to *only* the term after it?

Comment: @spraff that's really a follow-up question... but I added to my answer

Comment: Line breaks inside `[[` or *following* `&&` and `||` is fine.

Comment: The `!` already binds only to the term (pipeline) next to it. This suggestion therefore doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, didn't know that

Comment: Thanks @thatotherguy, fixed

Comment: While it doesn't matter in this specific case, you can also use `{ ...; }` instead of `( ... )` to avoid running the commands in a separate subshell

Comment: I'd negate that "doesn't matter" -- there's a performance hit for the subshell that `{ ...; }` avoids. If we were in a tight inner loop and only calling builtins, that subshell startup's cost could outweigh everything else.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy :-)

Comment: I worry more about someone copy-pasting this code and substituting `mkdir` for their own functions that try (and now fail) to exit or modify state. For performance, the `mkdirs` can be folded into one, potentially along with the `chmod` if you're [careful about -pm](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149559/why-does-mkdir-pm-not-set-the-permissions-i-asked-for)

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this in BASH:

```
if ! { mkdir -p "$available" &&
     mkdir -p "$enabled" &&
     mkdir -p "$logroot" &&
     chmod 755 "$available" "$enabled" "$logroot"; }
then
    echo "Could not make $available, $enabled, and $logroot."
fi
```

- `&&` allows you to enter next command in newline
- Instead of `! [[ ... ]]` you should use `! { ... }` as `[[ ... ]]` is used for evaluating [conditional expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html).

Comment: *grumbles re: unnecessary subshell*

Comment: Indeed should have been `{...}`